# Tkinter inner frame not updating on tab change

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I'm trying to use `tkinter` to create an app that can read and edit `json` values using input fields and then parse it in a later step.

I'm using the `tabview` to display different items.

When I change tabs, the content inside the tab is not displayed until I move the mouse out of the tab button. I'm trying to use `update_idletasks` to force an update and binded it to `tabchange`.

I was previously using `ctk.CTkTabview` as the parent class, but I had some troubles with limited customizability, so I switched to `ttk.notebook`.

when i was using ctk.CTkTabview i bound update_idletasks to segmented callback button and it seemed to work as it should.

```py
# Old code for ctk.CTkTabview
def _segmented_button_callback(self, selected_name):
        super()._segmented_button_callback(selected_name) 
        self.myRefresh()

def myRefresh(self, event = None):
        print("myRefresh")
        self.tab_frame.update_idletasks()
```

My new code triggers the `update_idletasks()` binded to `NotebookTabChanged`, but the frame inside is still blank until I move my mouse out of the button.

[image]

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import customtkinter as ctk

class BaseNotebook(ttk.Notebook):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class MyTabViewEq(BaseNotebook):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.tab_contents = {}  # To track content of each tab
        self.bind("<<NotebookTabChanged>>", self.fresh)

    def add_tab_with_content(self, tab_name, fields_and_values):
        # Check if tab already exists
        if tab_name in self.tab_contents:
            return  # Optionally, focus the existing tab instead of returning
        
        new_tab_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.add(new_tab_frame, text=tab_name)
        self.tab_contents[tab_name] = {"frame": new_tab_frame, "fields_and_values": fields_and_values, "entry_widgets": {}}
        tab_dict = {"test": "test", "test2": "test2"}
        # Populate the tab
        self.populate_tab(new_tab_frame, tab_name, tab_dict, fields_and_values)

        # Focus the newly created tab
        self.select(new_tab_frame)

    def populate_tab(self, tab_frame, tab_name, tab_dict, fields_and_values):

        scrollable_frame = ctk.CTkScrollableFrame(tab_frame)  # Assuming you have a scrolling mechanism
        scrollable_frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)
        # self.tab_contents[tab_name]["scrollable_frame"] = scrollable_frame

        self.tab_contents[tab_name]["scrollable_frame"] = scrollable_frame

        dict_frame = tk.Frame(scrollable_frame)  # Specify corner radius for rounded corners if desired
        dict_frame.pack(fill='x', padx=10, pady=(10, 0), expand=True)

        button = ttk.Button(dict_frame, text="Save Button", command=self.buttonclick)
        button.pack(side='left', padx=10, pady=10)
        
        # tab top info
        for key, value in tab_dict.items():
            label = tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text=f"{key}: {value}")
            label.pack(padx=10, pady=5, anchor='w')

        input_fields_frame = tk.Frame(scrollable_frame)
        input_fields_frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.populate_input_fields(tab_name, input_fields_frame, fields_and_values)

    def fresh(self, event=None):
        current_tab = self.nametowidget(self.select())
        if hasattr(current_tab, 'update_idletasks'):
            print(current_tab)
            current_tab.update_idletasks()
        else:
            print("No update_idletasks")

    def buttonclick(self):
        print("button clicked")
        
    def populate_input_fields(self, tab_name, frame, fields_and_values):
        entry_widgets = self.tab_contents[tab_name]["entry_widgets"]
        for row, (name, value) in enumerate(fields_and_values.items()):
            label = tk.Label(frame, text=f"{name}:")
            label.grid(row=row, column=0, pady=10, sticky="w")
            entry = tk.Entry(frame)
            entry.grid(row=row, column=1, pady=10, sticky="ew", padx=(5, 20))
            frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
            entry_widgets[name] = entry
            entry.insert(0, value)
def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("600x400")

    # Example fields and values
    fields_and_values = {
        'Field1': 'Value1',
        'Field2': 'Value2',
        'Field3': 'Value3',
    }

    notebook = MyTabViewEq(root)
    notebook.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

    # Adding a sample tab
    notebook.add_tab_with_content("Tab 1", fields_and_values)
    notebook.add_tab_with_content("Tab 2", fields_and_values)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @СергейКох I changed it to a minimal reporoducible example

Comment: In Windows 10 your problem cannot be reproduced. What OS do you have?

Comment: @СергейКохi i'm using an m1 Pro, with macOS 14.3.1

Comment: Try reinstalling Tkinter.

Comment: Try installing Python downloaded from python.org.

Comment: I've uninstalled every python i've installed with brew and installed a new one from python.org. Also created a new venv.

The problem still persists :(